# Overlfow:hidden on div

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have section with 2 divs in it. One of divs is a text layer and part of it's text needs to be hidden.
I can't figure the reason why `overflow: hidden` isn't working.

Basically I only need to word Harder till the D to be visible.

```css
.work-harder {
    background-color: rgb(64, 68, 230);
    height: auto;

}

.work-harder #background {
    width: 1920px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 30px 0 0 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 208px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(26, 27, 86, 0.188);
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    }
    
    .work-harder .content {
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px;
}

.work-harder .content p {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.111;  
    width: 60%;
    padding: 130px 0 0 350px; 
    margin: 0; 
}

.work-harder .content button {
    color: rgb(41, 41, 53);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 60px;  
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 70px 0 0 350px;
}

.content img {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section class="work-harder">
                <div id="background">Work harder</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>
                        <p>Aenean bibendum lacus sed ex commodo, pretium rutrum turpis elementum.</p>
                        <button type="submit" class="check">
                            <span>Check it</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/work-harder.png" alt="Macbook image">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.work-harder {
    background-color: rgb(64, 68, 230);
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}
```

will do. `overflow: hidden;` needs to be specified on the containing element and since you're positioning background `absolute`, the parent container needs to be relative in order to become the 'origin' of absolute.